# Source of MemoryError in numpy/ma/core.py

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, memory

While running my python scripts on some simulations on a x86-64 CentOS with a 
Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit), I started receiving the following error message pertaining to the memory use of the computer. I am not sure how to reproduce the error given the large size of the intermediate-level script. Please let me know if I should upload the entire `gizmo_plot.py` script in here to get help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DLA_DM.py", line 102, in <module>
    gizmo.plot.Image.plot_image()
  File "/usr5/username/simulation/gizmo/gizmo_plot.py", line 623, in plot_image
    vmin=image_limits[0], vmax=image_limits[1],
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1867, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5511, in imshow
    im.autoscale_None()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 363, in autoscale_None
    self.norm.autoscale_None(self._A)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 1066, in autoscale_None
    self.vmin = A.min()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 5587, in min
    result = self.filled(fill_value).min(
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 3718, in filled
    result = self._data.copy('K')
MemoryError
```

Comment: The traceback indicates that there isn't enough memory to make a copy of some array.  It could be that the array is so big there isn't room for a duplicate, or that the cumulative use of memory (this and other arrays) is pushing the limits.

Comment: Yes, indeed arrays are very big on the order 10^7. And I am not sure if there is anyway to to fix it.

Comment: The traceback looks like it's making a temporary copy of the array/image while figuring out the 'color' range, I suppose for scaling that part of the display.  Plotting is a complex action.  I don't think there's a lot you can do to reduce its memory usage.

Comment: After reducing the size of my arrays by increasing the size of the resolution element, I was able to by-pass the error. Thank You